# Cohomology of a monad.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, exact-sequence, sheaf-cohomology

**Definition**. A monad over a projective variety $X$ is a complex $$M : 0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{A} \stackrel{f} {\longrightarrow} \mathcal{B} \stackrel{g} {\longrightarrow} \mathcal{C} \longrightarrow 0$$ of coherent sheaves over $X$ which is exact at $\mathcal{A}$ and at $\mathcal{C}$, that means $g \circ f = 0$, $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective. The coherent sheaf $E : = \dfrac{\text{Ker}(g)}{Im(f)}$ will be called cohomology of $M$.

Consider the monad $M$ and the exact sequences associated with it.

$$M : 0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(-1) \stackrel{f} {\longrightarrow} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}^{\oplus 4} \stackrel{g} {\longrightarrow} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(1) \longrightarrow 0$$

$$0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(-1) \longrightarrow  K \longrightarrow E \longrightarrow 0 \tag{1}$$

$$ 0 \longrightarrow K \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}^{\oplus 4} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(1) \longrightarrow  \tag{2}0 $$

$$0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(-1) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}^{\oplus 4}  \longrightarrow Q \longrightarrow 0 \tag{3}$$ and

$$0 \longrightarrow E \longrightarrow Q \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}(1) \longrightarrow 0 \tag{4}$$

where $K = \text{Ker}(g)$, $Q = \text{coker}(f)$ and $E$ is the cohomology of $M$.

In this case, we have that $E$ is a instanton sheaf of charge $c = 1$. As your dual $E^\vee$ is a reflexive sheaf and $E \simeq E^{\vee}$ we have that $E$ is a  reflexive sheaf.

**The goal here is  to calculate** $\text{dim}Hom \bigl( E \otimes T_{\mathbb{P}^{3}} \bigr) = h^{0}(E^{\vee} \otimes T_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}) = h^{0}(E \otimes T_{\mathbb{P}^{3}})$.

**My attempt**.

By [I, see proposition 19] we have $E$ is locally free and stable.

Twisting the Euler sequence by $E$, we get $$ 0 \longrightarrow E \longrightarrow E(1)^{\oplus 4} \longrightarrow E \otimes  T_{\mathbb{P}^{3}} \longrightarrow 0 \tag{5}$$

By [II, see Lemma 1.2.5] we have $H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{3}, E_{norm} = E) = 0$, because $c_{1}(E) = 0$.

Now, by [III, see Corollary 3.3] we have that $E$ is $1$-regular. So $H^{i}( E(1-i)) = 0$ for all $i > 0$.

Even with this information and using the exact sequences (1), (2), (3) and (4), I still haven't been able to reach the goal mentioned above.

Any help is most welcome.

Thank you very much.

I) Instanton Sheaves on Complex Projective Space. (Marcos Jardim),

II) Vector Bundle on Comlex Projective Spaces. (Okonek),

III) Monads and Regularity of Vector Bundles on Projective Varieties. (M.Miró-Roig).

Comment: How is the usage of "monad" in this post related to the category-theoretic construction (an endofunctor plus two natural transformations, etc)?

Comment: @Kreiser. Excuse me, but I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Why do you call this thing a monad? Is it related to the usual notion of monad from category theory (the one you've tagged this question with)? If so, how? If not, where does this term come from? I could not find a reference to a monad in the algebraic geometry literature that was not the category theory version of a monad (though perhaps I have not found the right place to look). Additional unrelated question: what are $f,g$ in your post?

Comment: I am interested in the existence or not of injective morphisms of a sheaf that is the cohomology of a monda and the tangent space $T_{\mathbb{P}^{3}}$.

Comment: Please, see the definition in reference II above.

Comment: I do not have access to that book because libraries are closed where I am (pandemic). Surely you could say a couple words in a comment about this. You also did not define $f$ and $g$ in your post - this is probably even more important.

Comment: @KReiser This is a very common usage of the term monad in the algebraic geometry setting. For projective spaces, it is a three term complex, where all terms are direct sum of line bundles, the left map is injective, right map is surjective and the middle cohomology is a vector bundle. $f,g$ above could be any such maps making it into a monad, so there could be many choices for these, apriori giving several middle cohomolgies.

Comment: Thank you for your support @Mohan.

Comment: I edited the question with the definition of  a monad.

Comment: @Mohan thanks for the help - apparently I hang out with the wrong crowd of algebraic geometers to be familiar with this notion. Is there any relation to the category-theoretic terminology, or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $E$ is 1-regular, it is $m$-regular for all $m>0$. Then, $h^0(E)=\chi(E)$ and same for $E(1)$. From your (5), since $H^1(E)=0$, we get, $h^0(E\otimes T_{\mathbb{P}^3})=4 h^0(E(1))-h^0(E)=4\chi(E(1))-\chi(E)$. Using (1) and (2), you can easily calculate these.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mohan.